# how do i properly use php sqlite3 prepare and bind 2 values to it?

Tags: php, sqlite

trying to create a login page using sqlite3

```
    $db = new SQLite3('mydb.db');
    $username = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
    $password = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['password']));

    $q    = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username=':username' and password=':password'");
    $stmt = $q ->bindValue(':username', $username, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $stmt = $q ->bindValue(':password', $password, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $stmt ->execute();
    $row  = $stmt->fetchArray();

    if($row > 0)
    {
        echo 'Successfully logged in.';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Error';
    }
```

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean**

Comment: What you are trying to do is dangerous. Please [read](https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/), [these](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2006-12-15-never-store-passwords-in-a-database.html), [and](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Plaintext_Storage), [these](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/). Anyone, who answers your question as it is without a warning is not looking out for you.

Comment: I'll check them out but i just need to know what I'm doing wrong and how to do it the right way

Comment: Please don't store passwords as plaintext, ever.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are declaring `$q` as your `SQLite3Stmt` instance but you are binding and executing `$stmt`.

You must initialize the `$stmt` with `$db->prepare` in order to properly bind your values in the query and then to execute it.

```
$db = new SQLite3('mydb.db');
$username = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
$password = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['password']));

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username = :username and password = :password");
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', $password, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmt->execute();

//Returns an array if user exists, if not then returns FALSE.
$exists  = $stmt->fetchArray();

if($exists === false)
{
    echo 'Error';
}
else 
{
    echo 'Successfully logged in.'; 
}
```

Comment: appreciate pointing it out..though im still getting a 
Call to a member function execute() on boolean..

also.. should binding be done in 1 line somehow?

Comment: Just after `$stmt ->execute();` add the following code: `echo $db->lastErrorMsg();` ... this should explain your error message better. Share the error message it displays.

Comment: @user837288 I believe I found your issue. I have edited my answer to reflect the change. Disregard my comment about the bindValue problems, you binded them correctly initially.

Comment: nice one.. almost there now Object of class SQLite3Stmt could not be converted to int for the if ($stmt > 0) statement

Comment: just edited the last comment appreciate your efforts.. im just trying this now : if($stmt > 0)
  {
   echo 'Successfully logged in.';
  }
  else 
  {
   echo 'Invalid username/password.';
  }

Comment: ending up with Object of class SQLite3Stmt could not be converted to int

Comment: @user837288 I have updated my answer to help you with that issue. `$stmt->fetchArray();` returns the row's information as an array, not just a count.

Comment: this is depressing but i thank your patience.. Call to undefined method SQLite3Stmt::fetchArray()

Comment: @user837288 that code is correct, I cannot see anything wrong with this code. [If you check here](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue.php) you will see your code is almost identical to the examples.

Comment: that's where i got the code from actually but im worried that bindValue should be in 1 line, just like when you use return, if you need to return multiple values it has to be in an array